# how to count sum for specific year in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

i have data given below in Google Sheet

```
    jumlah      tanggal
1   Rp15.000    15-Apr-2020
2   Rp15.000    15-Mei-2020
3   Rp15.000    15-Jun-2020
4   Rp15.000    15-Jul-2020
5   Rp15.000    18-Agu-2020
6   Rp15.000    15-Sep-2020
7   Rp15.000    20-Okt-2020
8   Rp15.000    18-Nov-2020
9   Rp15.000    12-Des-2020
10  Rp15.000    11-Jan-2021
11  Rp15.000    15-Feb-2021
12  Rp15.000    15-Mar-2021
```

how can i only sum column "*jumlah*" only from year *2020*?
[update]
i'm already follow some answer but it's still error
[image: sumproduct error]

Comment: Try seeing https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2013/02/26/sum-for-a-date-range-in-excel/  And let me know did it helped

Comment: i will try it :)

Comment: @GajJulije can you give me the formula? i cofused with your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for people who trying to help. So far i'm trying every solution above but it doesn't work. I googling many times for everyday then get the solution.

here's the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C3:C)=2020)*B3:B)
```

here's the link to the sites:
https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/sumproduct.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
=sumproduct(year(C2:C)=2020, B2:B)
```

You will need to exclude row 1 as C1 is not a date and `year(C1)` will give an error.

This formula creates a column of true/false values depending on whether the year is 2020 or not. Then multiples that column with the values in column B. And then adds it all up.